# How does the apply(fn) function in pytorch work with a function without return statement as argument?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have some questions about the following code fragments:

```
>>> def init_weights(m):
        print(m)
        if type(m) == nn.Linear:
            m.weight.data.fill_(1.0)
            print(m.weight)

>>> net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2, 2), nn.Linear(2, 2))
>>> net.apply(init_weights)
```

apply() is part of the pytorch.nn package. You find the code in the documentation of this package. The final questions:
1. Why does this code sample work, although there is no argument or brackets added to init_weights() when it is given to apply()?
2. Where does the function init_weights(m) gets its argument m from, when it's given as a parameter to the function apply() without brackets and an m?

Answer (score 15):

We find the answers to your questions in said documentation of [`torch.nn.Module.apply(fn)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.apply):

> Applies `fn` recursively to every submodule (as returned by [.children()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.children))
>   as well as self. Typical use includes initializing the parameters of a model
>   (see also [torch-nn-init](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch-nn-init)).

1. Why does this code sample work, althouh there is no argument or brackets added to init_weights() when it is given to apply()?

   - The given function `init_weights` isn't called prior to the `apply` call, precisely because there are no parentheses, rather a reference to `init_weights` is given to `apply`, and only from within `apply` later on `init_weights` is called.
2. Where does the function init_weights(m) gets its argument m from, when it's given as a parameter to the function apply() without brackets and an m?

   - It gets its argument with each call within `apply`, and, as the documentation tells, it is called for m iterating over every submodule of (in this case) `net` as well as `net` itself, due to the method call `net.apply(…)`.

Comment: Documentation moved to:
https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=apply#torch.nn.Module.apply

Answer (score 0):

[docs]`def apply(self: T, fn: Callable[['Module'], None]) -> T:`

```
   for module in self.children():
        module.apply(fn)
    ***fn(self)***
    return self
```

from https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.apply read the source code about apply, it's called fn(self) last